# +2 on accepting answers: something is wrong with my account on SO

Tags: support, status-bydesign, accepted-answer

I was doing my good SO citizen work this morning (revising answers to my questions and accepting them) whilst I noticed that my rep doesn't get increased with the usual +2 on each accepted answer.

What's wrong?

**Edit**: the question wasn't "Community Wiki".

**Edit**: the answer accepted wasn't mine in this instance.

**Example**: I just accepted [Access to widget in GTK+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072976/access-to-widget-in-gtk) and no +2 rep.

**Edit**: no mention of the "accept" transaction appears on my "envelope" page.

**Resolution:** the answer provided to the question was marked "Community Wiki" and thus no rep is awarded for accepting one of those.

Comment: Wonder if they were CW. And if they weren't, how about some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you at the +200 per day reputation cap?

I checked the database and you created and deleted multiple accepts on this post on 2010-01-16 from 12:14 to 12:38 UTC:

[Access to widget in GTK+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072976/access-to-widget-in-gtk/2073145#2073145)

Note that this particular post is marked Community Wiki by the author, so it won't confer rep.

All the other accepts look fine.

Comment: Not today but yesterday yes i.e. not within the same UTC based day.

Comment: Ah!  so if the answer is **cw** then I don't get rep... another interesting SO property.  I thought this was only on the **question** being a **cw**. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get the **+2** rep when you accept an answer under the following:

- On your own question answered by you
- Community wiki

[One of your recent accepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020480/last-fm-api-are-etag-last-modified-headers-supported) was on a question you yourself answered.

Comment: Thanks but this is not the case here i.e. CW & my answer.

Comment: The recently **attempted** was on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072976/access-to-widget-in-gtk . I retracted my accept until I cleared this matter.... and now I have accepted it without my usual +2...

Comment: @jldupont That answer was CW, maybe that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have recently received downvotes on [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073079/2073212#2073212) [of your](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073079/2073212#2073212) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070915/2070970#2070970), that's -2 each. Might this have coincided? Or does the "+2" really not appear on your [envelope page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/171461)?

Comment: no: I have made that check... but thanks for your contribution.

Comment: the +2 doesn't appear at all on my "envelope" page.